# Help with code on 4 x 4 x4 LED cube with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, led

Recently I made a LED cube, on my own, and  I want it to display characters, alphabets numbers going layer by layer using the concept of multiplexing and POV (persistence of vision). I googled a lot, searched on Instructables too, but I was unable to find an easy code to do what I want. I am only a beginner and don't have very much knowledge. Please provide a way I can go for.

[This is what I did](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gODIqwUPEk) one day ago.

Comment: heyy why are you getting too rude, i'm only a begginer and didn't know that it may require the wirings, well i was concerned with the software so i thought it may not be needed.

Comment: Finding the code for your application isn't easy, unless you followed a specific tutorial. Also, it's a too general question to be constructive and to suit this site. You should scope it more and provide some more details.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of examples if you Google enough, but depending on exactly what is is you want your cube to do you may not find the exact code (if you did, it wouldn't be much fun though ;-) )

The basic process with the firmware design would be to decide on a fixed timebase for your LED updates, for example 100Hz. Then create an **interrupt routine** which updates your LED data at this point. You can do it all in the main loop, but this is inefficient as the main loop is stuck waiting for the next update when it could be doing other things.

Every modern microcontroller has a timer peripheral, so you set this up to create the interrupt. In the interrupt routine you either update the data, or better is to set a flag which calls a routine in the main code. Ideally interrupt routines should be short and quick.

That's really about it for the general overview, for the connections you can either use shift registers, multiplexers or simply connect the LEDs directly if you have enough pins available. Although the output pins are capable or sourcing enough current to drive a typical LED, given the number the overall power consumption would likely exceed specs, so you will need a transistor to drive each LED (or use the shift register, other driver ICs mentioned above)

I would just jump right in and start experimenting, have a read up on the timer peripheral and interrupts, and see what you come up with. Pinch snippets of useful code from various projects if you need to. Try and approach the process in a modular fashion, so you can test each smaller part as you go along, then put them all together.
Then if you get stuck, come back with a specific question, and post your code and schematic so we can give you a detailed answer.

Comment: Also, for an easy start into timers, look at Timer1 and Timer3 libraries on the Arduino Playground at arduino.cc